# How to mock a maven repository?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, remote-server, aether

I am using Aether to manage and control maven dependencies of my project. I need to add unit tests that need maven dependency resolution.

How do I achieve this without talking to the real maven repo but mocking it using something like easy mock/mockito?

Comment: Instead of mocking a repository, have you thought about setting your own "test" repository up by installing Nexus somewhere and pointing to that?

Comment: thats a good idea too, thanks